# Google Sheets conditional formatting text in one cell effects another cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

i'm trying to format a cell so;

IF Cell E3 text contains "Long" I want Cell K3 cell to turn RED when text contains "Bearish"

IF Cell E4 text contains "Long" I want Cell K4 cell to turn GREEN when text contains "Bullish"

IF Cell E5 text contains "Long" I want Cell K5 cell to turn ORANGE when text contains "Indecision"

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### red:

```
=(K3="Bearish")*(E3="Long")
```

### green:

```
=(K3="Bullish")*(E3="Long")
```

### orange:

```
=(K3="Indecision")*(E3="Long")
```

[image]